# Where to add skip-name-resolve? in my.cnf or server.cnf?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, config

i need some help editing the correct file. I like to add "skip-name-resolve=1" to the my.cnf file. I am using centos7 and mariadb 10.5.

I found a file in /etc/my.cnf. This is the content:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = ::ffff:127.0.0.1
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

I struggle with the last line "!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d" and the excamation mark.
in the folder my.cnf.d i have these files:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  295 Nov  2 12:37 client.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  763 Nov  2 12:37 enable_encryption.preset
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  232 Nov  2 12:37 mysql-clients.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  157 Nov  1 21:13 plesk-utf8mb4.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1080 Nov  2 12:37 server.cnf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  120 Nov  2 12:37 spider.cnf
```

Did i need to add "skip-name-resolve=1" to the server.cnf because this file is inside the includedir? Or did i need to add it to my.cnf after the line socket=...?

Because in server.cnf there is [mysqld] too.

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see
#
# See the examples of server my.cnf files in /usr/share/mysql/
#

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Galera-related settings
#
[galera]
# Mandatory settings
#wsrep_on=ON
#wsrep_provider=
#wsrep_cluster_address=
#binlog_format=row
#default_storage_engine=InnoDB
#innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#
# Allow server to accept connections on all interfaces.
#
#bind-address=0.0.0.0
#
# Optional setting
#wsrep_slave_threads=1
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.5 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.5]
```

Comment: Inside the `[mysqld]` section

Comment: As explained i have 2 [mysqld] sections one in my.cnf and one in server.cnf. I am not sure where exactly?

Answer (score 0):

1.`ps -ef|grep mysql`
You can view the my.cnf file in use now.
2. Stop the database service and add parameters to vi my.cnf.
`skip-name-resolve`
3. Start the database for testing.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of organization, put it in the server.cnf file.

Configuration files are read in a particular order, from /etc/my.cnf down to your user ~/.my.cnf. See [this MariaDB doc for the current order](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/#default-option-file-locations-on-linux-unix-mac) for your operating system. MySQL/MariaDB will read the last value set when it reads these configuration files in order.

The files under the includedir are [read in alphabetical order](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/#option-file-syntax).

You can also [print the configuration values](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-with-option-files/#option-groups) to see what is being set by your set of configuration files.